# How to delete or disable Helvetica fonts from macOS?

Tags: macos, fonts, macbook

Since macOS has Helvetica fonts and websites are putting Helvetica fonts at the beginning of `font-family`, it makes all the websites are looking very ugly. I really don't like Helvetica fonts at all. I tried to `sudo rm /System/Library/Fonts/Helvetica*`, but it gave me “Operation not permitted” errors. I just want to disable or get rid of it. And never want to see these fonts at all.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica is one of the most used fonts in the world, and obviously, if some websites want to display their text using Helvetica, or use it as a fallback, that's their choice.

The solution is *not* to force-remove a system font, as that is very likely to break your operating system, since Helvetica is a default system font that has been shipped with macOS [for a long time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_macOS#System_fonts_up_to_Mac_OS_X_10.7_Lion).

Instead, you should change the default sans-serif font in your browser:

- Under Chrome, go to `chrome://settings/fonts`, and select a different default.
- Under Firefox, go to `about:preferences#general`, and under *Fonts & Colors*, click *Advanced*.

Or you could enable a browser extension like [Stylish](https://userstyles.org/) (which was [caught stealing user data](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/07/05/browsers_pull_stylish_but_invasive_browser_extension/), so use at your own risk after reading the ToS) or [Stylus](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus) (a clone that does not phone home). With these extensions, you can override the stylesheets of websites—you may even use Comic Sans, if you so prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Actually I did change fonts in chrome to other fonts such as `Droid San` and `Liberation Mono` etc... before posting this question. But I still think it's `Helvetica`. maybe it's not.. it looks different from my Linux's chrome. At least it looks much bolder. I am not sure why...

Comment: I found the solution. The website has to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to the style to make it look normal in macos.

Comment: Okay, interesting detail, good to know.